# Actionfunction onComplete works abnormally

Tags: actionfunction

Please help about the issue.
I have onComplete on actionfunction called by button, and called function is another actionfunction that return PageReference for moving to next page.

When I click button at the first it doesn't move to next page, after then, I click it again, it works, moving to next Page.
Why is this happening? Code below.

```
<script>
    function moveT(){
        movemove(
            document.getElementById("Name").value,
            document.getElementById("Email").value,
            document.getElementById("Phone").value,
            document.getElementById("Source").value,
        );
    }
</script>
<apex:form>

<Button class="col-mx-6  col-md-6" onclick="moveT()">Go to Next Page</Button>

<apex:actionFunction name="movemove" action="{!saveParams}" reRender="panel" oncomplete="moveToNext()">
    <apex:param name="Param1" assignTo="{!Param1}" value=""/>
    <apex:param name="Param2" assignTo="{!Param2}" value=""/>
    <apex:param name="Param3" assignTo="{!Param3}" value=""/>
    <apex:param name="Param4" assignTo="{!Param4}" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>
<apex:actionFunction name="moveToPrevious" action="{!moveTo0}"/>
<apex:actionFunction name="moveToNext" action="{!moveTo2}"/>

</apex:form>
```

---

```
public void saveParams(){
    // some data modification
    // No Page related action.
}

public PageReference moveTo2(){
        PageReference pg;
        pg = Page.VFPage2;

        return pg;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where have you define `moveT()` method invoked in onclick?

Comment: @Reshma Oops, sorry. I edited it

Comment: @Reshma, All 4params are stored in Controller value as expected. just page moving is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A button causes a form submit. You need to cancel that the default behavior, so that it doesn't happen:

```
<button class="col-mx-6  col-md-6" onclick="moveT(); return false;">Go to Next Page</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! With "return false" the oncomplete worked
If not, it was random, sometimes it worked and other times it didn't